# how to jump to the next video when current video file is not available?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am trying to play list of video files stored in a folder one by one but if any of the file is missing or deleted the program will stop but i want it jump to the next video and continue its execution is there any way to catch this error and jump to the next one?

```
function advanceVideo()
{          
  video_count++;
  if (video_count > num_files) video_count = 1; 
  videoPlayer.setAttribute("src","video/video"+video_count+".ogg");  
  video.load();
  video.play();     
}
```

I am using the above function for accessing the video file in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the various events the [`<video />`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element) element offers

```
// function to load the next video (without .play())
function advanceVideo() {
    video_count = (video_count + 1) % num_files;

    this.setAttribute("src", "video/video" + video_count + ".ogg");
    this.load();
}

// if the current video has reached the end, load the next
videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", advanceVideo);

// if the browser fetched enough data to play the video start playing
videoPlayer.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    this.play();
});

// if an error occured load the next video
videoPlayer.addEventListener("error", advanceVideo);
```

**Update**
This should do what you've requested in your comment

```
var num_files = 2,
    playedVideos = 0;

// load next video
function advanceVideo() {
    // current video id or -1 if not found
    var curId = parseInt((/video(\d+)\.ogg$/.exec(this.src) || [, -1])[1], 10);

    // reset if all videos have been played
    if (playedVideos == num_files) {
        playedVideos = 0;
        curId = -1;
    }

    this.src = "video/video" + (curId + 1) + ".ogg";
    this.load();
}

// if the current video has reached the end, load the next
videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    playedVideos++;
    advanceVideo();
});

// if the browser fetched enough data to play the video start playing
videoPlayer.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    this.play();
});

// if an error occured load the next video
videoPlayer.addEventListener("error", advanceVideo);
```

If there are less videos to play than `num_files` indicates, this will end in an "infinite loop" as it will try all videos until `curId` reaches the value `Infinity`!

Comment: in this code the last video will not be display... suppose i have v0,v1,v2 files and if i delete v1 video num_files will become 2 and will never get video_count=2 so last video will be missed always so is their any way to avoid it?

Comment: @user3145475 I've updated my answer with a possible solution to adapt the requirement from your comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using `try-catch` block:

```
function advanceVideo()
{          
  video_count++;
  if (video_count > num_files) video_count = 1;       
  videoPlayer.setAttribute("src","video/video"+video_count+".ogg");  
  try {        
    video.load();
    video.play();      
  } catch (e) { }
}
```